# Работа с аргументами функции PHP

Tags: php

Есть функция f() с 3 аргументами. Над каждым аргументом выполняется операция (одна и та же). Подскажите, как записать это в цикле, чтобы не множить строки кода. Есть функция `func_get_args()` но она даёт массив значений. А мне нужно производить перезапись в локальную переменную функции.

```
function f($a,$b,$c){
       $a = trim($a);
       $b = trim($b);
       $c = trim($b);
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте `foreach (func_get_args() as &$val) { ... }`

Comment: Теперь ещё больше вопросов появилось
function f($a){
  foreach (func_get_args() as &$val){
      $val = '111';}
  echo $a;
    }
f('555');

Вообще ничего не даёт

Comment: Попытка не пытка. Боюсь без массива в том или ином виде вам не обойтись. Использовать локальные переменный (аргументы функции) при этом не получится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Подскажите, как записать это в цикле, чтобы не множить строки кода*

```
$a = ' a ';
$b = ' b ';
$c = ' c ';

[$a, $b, $c] = f($a, $b, $c);
var_dump($a, $b, $c);


function f(...$args): array
{
    return array_map('trim', $args);
}
```

---

Результат:

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
string(1) "c"
```